# PrimeNg Calendar default date in UTC

Tags: angular, date, calendar, primeng, utc

I would like to force p-calendar, to always show UTC today date, when click on empty calendar field. I know there is defautlDate option, but this property is set with component init, and it is not updating "onLive". I just want to force calendar not using client timezone. Thanks a lot for any help.